# Load report failed- Crystal Report in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I have this application in C# on VS2012, in which I need to generate Crystal Report 13.0.x. This application has been running fine for last 2 years or so . Recently did some addons and after that its giving error

> Load Report Fail

However strange thing is that , in a day around 100 times this Crystal report is generated and in between it gives out that error. After the whole application has to be exited and then it works fine too. Because of this I am not abel to replicate the error at me end. 

Here my code:

```
   public partial class ChangeOrderList : Form
{
    ConnectionClass connectionclass = new ConnectionClass();
    NewOrderBL NObl = new NewOrderBL();
    DailySalesReportBL DSRbl = new DailySalesReportBL();
    public ChangeOrderList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void ChangeOrderList_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /////////////////////////To count Lunch Buffet///////////////////

        DataTable dtlb = DSRbl.selectBuffet(DateTime.Today.Date.ToString(), DateTime.Today.Date.ToString());
        string date = dtlb.Rows[0][0].ToString();


        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        try
        {

            string sqlqry = "Select KOTNo,TableNo,WaiterName,ItemCode,ItemName,Quantity,Status,Foodtype from tblOrderChange where KOTNo=@kotno and Quantity>'0.00' and (Category!='Appetizer' and Category!='Indian Breads' and Category!='Desserts' and Category!='Beverages' and Category!='Tandoori')";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlqry, connectionclass.con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kotno", NewOrderBL.KOTNo);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);


            DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "tblOrderChange");
            if (ds.Tables["tblOrderChange"].Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Data Found", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            if (deliverybl.order == "Delivery")
            {
                //PrintDelivery printorder = new PrintDelivery();
                ChangeOrderdelivery printorder = new ChangeOrderdelivery();
                printorder.SetDataSource(ds);
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = printorder;
                System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument printDocument = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
                printorder.PrintOptions.PrinterName = printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
                printorder.PrintOptions.PrinterName = "EPSON TM-U220 Receipt";
                printorder.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
                ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();
                ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
                ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
                paramField.Name = "LBqty";
                paramDiscreteValue.Value = date;
                paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
                paramFields.Add(paramField);

                PrintChangeOrderList printchangeorder = new PrintChangeOrderList();
                printchangeorder.SetDataSource(ds);
                printchangeorder.SetParameterValue("LBqty", date);
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = printchangeorder;
                System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument printDocument = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
                printchangeorder.PrintOptions.PrinterName = printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
                printchangeorder.PrintOptions.PrinterName = "EPSON TM-U220 Receipt";
                printchangeorder.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
            }



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        finally { connectionclass.disconnect(); }
        onlinebl.crystalreport = "";

        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        onlinebl.crystalreport = "";

        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

    }
```

I have been banging my head for long . Every where I search it says about the path and I am not using the path anywhere so not able to understand where the fault is.
If you need any more info or the code please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
       Check your class:

<pre>
           ChangeOrderdelivery printorder = new ChangeOrderdelivery();
            printorder.SetDataSource(ds);
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = printorder;


          this one has a report Path hidding i guess
          ChangeOrderdelivery printorder = new ChangeOrderdelivery();

  </pre>
```

Comment: How and where I can check that hidden path ?

Comment: On this class ChangeOrderdelivery, you can find the report  mostly in project path..

Comment: yes i got it its **D:\Kashif\RMS_Rectify_DSR_Delivery\ChangeOrderdelivery.rpt** so what should I change it to ?

Comment: if you can open the ChangeOrderdelivery class, check the path of the report upon calling on it.. it must be same as this D:\Kashif\RMS_Rectify_DSR_Delivery\ChangeOrderdelivery.rpt. its look like this  APPPATH = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/CrystalReport/ChangeOrderdelivery.rpt";
              
                report.Load(APPPATH);

Comment: Same as like this:D:\Kashif\RMS_Rectify_DSR_Delivery\ChangeOrderdelivery.rpt                                 APPPATH = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/RMS_Rectify_DSR_Delivery/ChangeOrderdelivery.rpt";  It must be 100% the same.

Comment: this path is for development PC and deployed on client's PC. So do I need to change anything ?

Comment: make sure the path on your deployment pc(if crystal report is working in here without any error) is same as the path of your client pc..i mean crystal report path.

Comment: I read that by changing build action to 'Compile' and Copy to output ' Copy  Alwyas' after doing so I am getting Error 'Unable to find the report in the manifest resources. Please build the project, and try again.' even reverting back to as previous it still giving error

Comment: your report must be in bin folder of the project then use this reportpath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/RMS_Rectify_DSR_Delivery/ChangeOrderdelivery.rpt"; then report.load(reportpath);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117700/discussion-between-mark-and-reds).

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted internet temp files and after that client has not yet complained about the error. So I am keeping an eye on it if it resolved the issue