# Unable to find the report in the manifest resources - Please build the project, and try again

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I was trying to fix the problem from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38429876/load-report-failed-crystal-report-in-c-sharp) 
when I read that changing the build action to `Compile` and Copy to output  `Copy Always` would fix the issue but it didnt. I tried reverting back to the previous settings but it didn't fix anything. Nothing mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408554/unable-to-find-the-report-in-the-manifest-resources-crystal-report-c-sharp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367624/unable-to-find-the-report-in-the-manifest-resources) helped either. How can I fix this error?

```
public override string ResourceName {
    get {
        return "PrintOrder.rpt";
    }
    set {
        // Do nothing
    }
}

public override string FullResourceName {
    get {
        return "GharAanganResturantManagement.PrintOrder.rpt";
    }
    set {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: Hardcoding resource names is a pretty bad idea, and not just because "Resturant" is misspelled.  Always favor the resource designer, Project > Properties > Resources.  Crystal reports in general ought to be left as files, they are too big to consider wasting the address space for them.  And modifying them is quite common.

Comment: @HansPassant its not hardcoded. Also checked spelling its misspelled everywhere so I think thats not the issue. So please advise